# Definite integral of Bessel function of the first kind times $x^{3/2}$

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, recurrences, bessel-functions

I am looking for preferably a closed form (or series solution if not possible) for the following integral:

$$\int_0^a x^{3/2} J_\nu (bx) dx$$

where $\nu$ is an integer. This 1D integral appears when taking the polar Fourier transform of a separable radially symmetric function in 2D that I would like to propagate using the angular spectrum method. I understand that I can express this as a finite Hankel transform of $\sqrt{x}$ but I was hoping there was an analytic solution for this simple case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral requires $\nu>-5/2$ for convergence, and then becomes a hypergeometric function:
$$\int_0^a x^{3/2} J_\nu (bx) dx=\frac{2^{1-\nu} a^{\nu+\frac{5}{2}} b^{\nu}}{(2 \nu+5) \Gamma (\nu+1)}\, _1F_2\left(\frac{\nu}{2}+\frac{5}{4};\frac{\nu}{2}+\frac{9}{4},\nu+1;-\frac{1}{4} a^2 b^2\right).$$

Comment: Thank you Carlo! Is there any further simplification if $\nu$ can only be an integer?

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of the hypergeometric function if $\nu$ is an integer; if $\nu$ is half-integer the integral is obviously elementary.

Comment: Hi, what would the integral be in that case?

Comment: What if $\nu=1$?

Comment: for half-integer order you can use the recursion relation for spherical Bessel functions given in https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06428 ; no simplification if $\nu=1$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of series
$$\int x^{3/2}\, J_\nu (bx)\, dx=\frac{1}{b^{5/2}}\int t^{3/2}\, J_\nu (t)\, dt$$
$$\int t^{3/2}\, J_\nu (t)\, dt=\frac {t^{\nu +\frac{5}{2}} }{2^{\nu-1} }\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(4 k+2 \nu +5) \Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (k+\nu +1)}\,\,\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{2 k}$$

If $a_k$ is the coefficient
$$\Bigg|\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k}\Bigg|=\frac{4 k+2 \nu +5}{(k+1) (k+\nu +1) (4 k+2 \nu +9)}$$
Asymptotically
$$\Bigg|\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k}\Bigg|=\frac 1{k^2}-\frac{\nu +3}{k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$

Probably a quite fast convergence